# a modal dialog that it's url has been copied not working properly

Tags: file-upload, modal-dialog, copy-and-paste

I've got a modal dialog with an upload control in it which is working with no       problems. but when i try to copy the modal dialog's url (right click ->       properties) and paste it in another window, the upload process of the upload       control is getting stucked.

Am I missing something here?
Any help would be very appreciated